# PHP Check for HTTP and HTTPS in the submitted URL through FORM

Tags: php, regex

I have this code which checks for `http://` in the URL submitted. But I want it to also check for `https://`. So I tried with an `or` in the `if` condition but it still checks only for `http://` and not `https://`.

Here is my code.

```
if(!preg_match("@^http://@i",$turl) or !preg_match("@^https://@i",$turl)){
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid Target URL! Please input a standard URL with <span class='text-info'>http://</span> for example <span class='text-info'>http://www.kreatusweb.com</span> </div>";
}
```

If I now put `https://` in the URL and submit, it still returns this error message as now `http://` is false here. What logic or code should I use here to check for both. I just don't want users to submit `www.somewebsite.com`. I want them to submit full URL using either `http://` or `https://`. If either of these two exists in the URL then only the form will be processed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the `or` with `&&`

```
if(!preg_match("@^http://@i",$turl) && !preg_match("@^https://@i",$turl))
```

I used to do this logic mistake when I started to code because you think like this `if (not something or not somethingelse)`

but doing `if (!http || !https)` will return true in both http and https because

1- if it is http, then the `!https` part will return true

2- if it is https, then the `!http` part will return true too

Comment: That worked. How could I miss checking it with && operator. Feeling funny. Maybe because I haven't slept overnight. My mind needs some serious rest. Thanks anyway. I can go to bed now. :)

Comment: You are welcome, yes most of the nights I sleep with unresolved problems in, I find the solution in the next day morning. Go get some rest :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the regex so the `s` is optional by just adding a `?` after it.

```
if(!preg_match("@^https?://@i",$turl)){
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PHP validate filters at http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php.

```
<?php

$arr = [ 'http:example.com','https:/example.com','https://www.example.com','http://example.com',
'ftp://example.com','www.example.com','www.example.com/test.php','https://www.example.com/test.php?q=6'];

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    $filtered = filter_var($str,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL,FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED|FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED);
    if (!empty($filtered)) {
        if (stripos($filtered,'http') === 0) {
            echo $str.' is valid'.PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo $str.' is a valid URL, but not HTTP'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo $str.' is not a valid URL'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```